# How to differentiate two ipc renderer in one ipc main (same channel)

Tags: electron, ipc, ipcmain

I want to detect the specific frame/browserWindow. I have one main process and two browser windows which all three are sending message to each other using same channel . in IPCMain I need to detect one of them. I saw that IPCmain event has a function named frameId but when I use it I get undefined.

```
ipcMain.once("postMessage", (event, message) => {
    if(!activeRequest) return;
    activeRequest.json(message).send();
});
```

Comment: You want to know the browser window that sent the `postMessage` event?

Comment: yes. currently I am having two browserWindow connecting to main process with same event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can the get the current webcontent id from the main process by accessing the sender object in the events object which is the first argument.

```
   console.log(event.sender.webContents.id);
```

you can also pass the id of the window that the eent is coming from via the renderer process.

```
  // in the renderer process do this
  electron.ipcRenderer.send("new-message", { 
      winId: electron.remote.getCurrentWebContents().id , 
      message: "Hi"
  });
```

when the main process receives this event, you just have to access the `winId` property in the message object

Comment: Just adding to this, currently in Electron, you can just do `event.sender.id` to get the id.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can pass the identity in ipc message payoad, or you can get the windows web content id via, ipc message's sender object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did the first option but I was looking for alternative. can you please tell me how can I get the window content id? I tried couple of ways to get the id but no success.

Comment: You can get in event.sender object which is available in the ipc.on callback. Event.sender.senderId will contain the window content id of the sender